# how to get gridview selected row value to text box

Tags: javascript

I have a table which contains values in td's and a form with dropdowns and textboxes.

I need to put the td's value in the form's textbox (edit page) using javascript. The row header of the table is same as textboxes label name.

Comment: what  have you tried already ?

Comment: i am not able to understand how to approach.

Comment: i am very new in programming.

Comment: show your code in your question